# How do I figure out what's caching the DNS for a specific domain?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

I'm using linux (openSUSE 13.2) on my computer and my router is DD-WRT. There is a domain that, when I ping, keeps returning the wrong IP address.

My Router has the domain name server as Google's 8.8.8.8.

When I checked the domain there, it shows the correct IP (but ping shows the old one):

```
#this returns the CORRECT IP
nslookup thewebsite.com 8.8.8.8
```

On my computer, I ran:

```
sudo service nscd restart
```

On the router (via the web interface), I ran:

```
stopservice dnsmasq
startservice dnsmasq
```

Despite all that, I keep getting the wrong IP from ping. How do I figure out what's caching it and clear it?

Comment: rather than worry about how the cache is managed for now, reboot the router, then test. reboot the client and test. if its still a problem, reboot both devices before testing. Once you have the device isolated, you can look into what software is responsible and the procedure necessary to flush the cache.

Comment: @FrankThomas I discovered the issue. KDE has a cache application that's turned on by default (that i'd never heard of) and turning it off fixed the issue

Comment: @DonRhummy Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE has a cache application that's turned on by default (that i'd never heard of) and turning it off fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

After executing `sudo service nscd restart` --> `stopservice dnsmasq` --> `startservice dnsmasq` please try `ifconfig eth0 down` and `ifconfig eth0 up`. This is make the eth0 disable and re-enable. I had the same issue few years back and I got this working after re-enabling the interface.

Please make sure to enter the right eth number, in my case it was eth0. Let me know if you have any questions.